# Kotlin, Api Get request sometimes ends before returning anything

Tags: android, kotlin

I created an API request from a kotlin app to a server with Retrofit.
Sometimes the request return nothing, but it always return the data inside web URL.

My code

```
interface ApiService {

    @get:GET("main")
    val posts : Call<List<Products?>?>
```

```
class mainConnector {

    fun MainConnector(): Call<List<Products?>?> {

        val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()

        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
        val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(logging).build()

        val builder = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(ApiService.URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient)
            .build()

        val API = builder.create(ApiService::class.java)
        val call = API.posts

        return call
    }
```

This a part of activity that call the connector

```
        val obj = mainConnector()
        val call = obj.MainConnector()

        call.enqueue(object:Callback<List<Products?>?>{
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<Products?>?>,
                response: Response<List<Products?>?>
            ) {

                var postlist : List<Products?>? = response.body() as List<Products?>
                var list = mutableListOf<Products?>()
                val listView: ListView = findViewById(R.id.listview)
                listView.isClickable = true

                for(i in postlist!!.indices) {
                    list.add(
                        Products(postlist!![i]!!.admindescription,
                        postlist!![i]!!.created_at,
                        postlist!![i]!!.description,
                        postlist!![i]!!.id,
                        postlist!![i]!!.link,
                        postlist!![i]!!.pname,
                        postlist!![i]!!.price,
                        postlist!![i]!!.smalldescription,
                        postlist!![i]!!.updated_at,
                        postlist!![i]!!.user_id,
                        postlist!![i]!!.image,
                        postlist!![i]!!.category,
                        postlist!![i]!!.phone,
                        postlist!![i]!!.telegram,
                        postlist!![i]!!.name)
                    )
                }

                var adapter = MyMainListAdapter(this@MainActivity,R.layout.custom_main_list, list)
                listView.setOnItemClickListener{ parent, view, position, id ->
                    val name = postlist!![position]!!.pname
                    val createdAt = postlist!![position]!!.created_at
                    val description = postlist!![position]!!.description
                    val id = postlist!![position]!!.id
                    val link = postlist!![position]!!.link
                    val price = postlist!![position]!!.price
                    val smalldescription = postlist!![position]!!.smalldescription
                    val updatedAt = postlist!![position]!!.updated_at
                    val userId = postlist!![position]!!.user_id
                    val category = postlist!![position]!!.category
                    val phone = postlist!![position]!!.phone
                    val telegram = postlist!![position]!!.telegram
                    val userName = postlist!![position]!!.name

                    val i = Intent(this@MainActivity, ProductActivity::class.java)

                    val image = ArrayList<String?>()

                    for(i in postlist!![position]!!.image!!) {
                        image.add(i)
                    }

                    i.putStringArrayListExtra("image", image)
                    i.putExtra("name", name)
                    i.putExtra("createdAt", createdAt)
                    i.putExtra("description", description)
                    i.putExtra("id", id)
                    i.putExtra("link", link)
                    i.putExtra("price", price)
                    i.putExtra("smalldescription", smalldescription)
                    i.putExtra("updatedAt", updatedAt)
                    i.putExtra("userId", userId)
                    i.putExtra("category", category)
                    i.putExtra("phone", phone)
                    i.putExtra("telegram", telegram)
                    i.putExtra("userName", userName)

                    startActivity(i)
                }
                listView.setAdapter(adapter)
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Products?>?>, t: Throwable) {

            }

        })
```

As I said it sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't. So what's the problem here? (I'm mainly a php, js programmer and I am new in android and kotlin)

Comment: what is api response when it doesn't work

Comment: @GHH in browser all the data i need, but in app nothing